# Extracting subtitles of a mkv file using ffmpeg while downloading

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv, webtorrent

I am trying to stream a mkv file to a webpage, which is being downloaded using [WebTorrent](https://webtorrent.io/docs). The video file has ASS/SSA embedded subtitles. I am using electron to display the video, which uses chromium without proprietary codec support, so I have to use the following html:

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="video.mkv" type="video/webm">
<video/>
```

Since chrome supports webm and they use the same container, I can watch the video with audio. Webm doesn't support embedded subtitles, so the subtitles of the video get ignored.

I am extracting the subtitles using the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:2 sub.vtt
```

This works fine, but requires the file to be downloaded completely. Is it possible to extract the subtitles while the file is being downloaded, so that I can begin streaming the video together with the subtitles as soon as possible?

Comment: Why is not possible to use the embedded subtitles?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I updated the post.

Comment: Do you want to burn the subtitles in the video? Or do you plan to use the subtitles file in your client? Are you running ffmpeg on the client side? If that's the case, why not running it on the server where the video is?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón The source of the video is a torrent and I can't modify the file. Preferably I'd like to not burn them into the video. I want to keep the time between starting the download and watching the video as minimal as possible.